# How to Pass ViewModel from MVC Html to Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml file which uses for each loops from the value of the model that comes from controller.My cshtml code  is below:-

```
<tbody>
                                @foreach (var item model.TechnicianInvoice)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                                        @foreach (var rate in item.Rates)
                                        {
                                            <td class="td10"><span class="prefix">$</span><input  type="text" class="form-control my-input" value="@rate.Rate.ToString("0.00")"></td>
                                        }
                                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm" href="#" data-action="ShowPayTableModal" data-id="@item.Id" name="@item.Name">view</a></td>
                                        <td><a class="updateRate" data-id="@item">update</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
</tbody>
```

And `model.TechnicianInvoice` is a ist of view Model of:

```
public class TechnicianInvoiceViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TechRateViewModel> Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TechRateViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

Now What I need is when I click on the update button  the current foreach value of `model.Technician` should be passed into jquery. Currently I am using `data-id = @item` but when I console log this value only shows TechnicianInvoiceViewModel . My jquery code is

```
 $(".updateRate").on("click", function () {
                var data = $(this).attr("data-id");
                console.log(data);
});
```

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist that you want to parse a C# model into Javascript.
When you do `data-id = @item`, C# is asked for the string value of the item. But what do you expect this value to be? The Id? Then you should go for `data-id = @item.Id`. But there are plenty other options, it's also possible to return for example a JSON by implementing `@item.getJSON()` ...

Long story told short: You need to specify which value of your item you want to parse to your JavaScript ;)